# Why is the program throwing the SqlException: 'Incorrect syntax near 'ItemID'' every time its run?

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, ado.net

The goal of the program is to pull data from the database depending on the index value that you enter in and then display the data linked to that index in the console.

[image: code snapshot]

Comment: because you have incorrect syntax , why else would it show anything else if the syntax were not correct..? also show code not images of code learn to use the debugger and read the sql in the debugger bet you will find that `ItemQtyFrom` is not correct syntax.. put a space in between the `ItemQty and From`

Comment: See also: http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode. Avoid using concatenated strings to build SQL queries.

Comment: post your code instead of image, and read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're missing whitespaces before the `from` and `where` keywords. Additionally, `table` is a reserved word in SQL, so you'll have to escape it:

```
String selectStatement = "SELECT ItemID, ItemName, ItemQty " +
                         // Whitespace--------------------^
                         "FROM [Table] " + // [Table] is escaped
                         // Whitespace^
                         "WHERE ItemId = @ItemId"
```

Comment: Hey thx a million, it worked!!!

Answer (score 1):

Because you forgot to add space between **FROM table**

Here is updated query.

```
Select ItemId, ItemName, ItemQty "+
"From Table "+
"Where ItemId=@ItemId";
```

Comment: When I do that it gives me another another SqlException: "Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'Table'."

Comment: `Table` is a reserved word. Your table name is `Table` ?

Comment: Yeah I didnt know how to change the name lol, btw thx Amit Kumar and Squirrel.